# Удаление указателей из вектора в деструкторе. Вопрос  по поводу итератора.

Tags: c++

Вот код моего деструктора для класса MyClass

```
~MyClass()
{
    for ( std::vector< MyStruct* >::const_iterator ci = elements.begin();
        ci != clients.end(); ++ci )
    {
        delete *ci;
    }

    clients.clear();

}
```

Я использую `const_iterator`, всё компилится и работает. А может нужно использовать `iterator`. Всё-таки `const_iterator` говорит, что мы не будем изменять объект на который он указывает, а мы его удаляем - по сути изменение или я не прав? Верно, что у меня используется `const_iterator`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все верно. Ваш вектор хранит указатели (не константные), поэтому используя константный итератор вы можете изменять объекты на которые эти указатели ссылаются, но не можете изменять сами значения указателей:

```
 std::vector< MyStruct* >::const_iterator ci = elements.begin();
 *ci = &otherMyStruct; // нельзя
 (*ci)->someNonconstMethod(); //можно
```

Орератор delete не меняет значения указателя, поэтому после цикла значения указателей останутся прежними, однако они будут указывать на освобожденную область памяти.